# TypeError: Cannot read property '$invalid' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a tab inside a HTML form:

```
<div ng-switch-when="identification">
 <div ng-include="'register/individual/views/tabs/identificationView.html'">
 </div>
</div>
```

Inside the tab I have a button that will pop-up this modal when clicked:

```
<a class="btn-round" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addModal">Add</a>

<div ng-init="form={}" >
    <div ng-include=" 'register/individual/views/modal/addIdentification.html' "></div>
</div>
```

Inside my modal, I have a form that should show validations once the ng-click is triggered.

```
<form name="form.addIdentificationForm" novalidate> <div class="row" 
ng-if="ctrl.showValidationMessages && 
form.addIdentificationForm.identificationIssuer.$invalid">


<a class="btn btn-round" href="" ng-click="ctrl.submitForm2()"role="button">Ok</a>
```

Inside my controller:

```
$scope.form = {};

this.showValidationMessages2 = false;

this.isFormValid2 = function() {
  this.showValidationMessages2 =
    $scope.form.addIdentificationForm.$invalid;
  return !this.showValidationMessages2;
}

this.submitForm2 = function() {
  if (this.isFormValid2()) {
    console.log(this.isFormValid());
  }
}
```

But it shows an error:

> scripts-f852eceaf3.js:8 TypeError: Cannot read property '$invalid' of
>   undefined
>       at Object.isFormValid2 (scripts-f852eceaf3.js:29)

My controller is accessible inside the modal since I was able to display data to the textbox and dropdowns from my controller file. My only problem is this $invalid. Before I didn't include the form variable, I just read some questions here and applied that but the same issue even I will not include the form variable.

Comment: Use `name="formAddIdentificationForm"` and then `$scope.formAddIdentificationForm.$invalid;`

Comment: Remove `$scope.form = {};` from controller and try.